# How to get a WebSocket server run on aws

Tags: c++, ios, nginx, websocket, websocket++

I'm developing an iOS app that requires realtime dual-way server/client messaging.

I'm trying to use [WebSocket++](http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp) to develop a WebSocket server app on an AWS EC2. Have to use C++ because that's the only language I know on the server side.
The problem is I'm a fresh guy on server side development. I have 2 very basic questions:

1, Do I need have to setup an HTTP server like apache/nginx in order to get websocket running?
That is, can websocket app live independently alone?

2, I have now setup an nginx server in case it is a must have, is there any resource that I can refer to to make nginx & websocket work together well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you don't need a Web server, a (reverse) Web proxy or anything to have your C++ WebSocket server talk to WebSocket clients.
2. Nginx (as HAproxy) supports reverse proxying WebSocket. This can make sense in certain situations, like you want to terminate TLS at the proxy and forward plain WebSocket to your backend server, or you want to load-balance incoming WebSocket connections to multiple backend nodes. However, as said, this isn't required.

Comment: So when I'm trying to connect to the websocket server, how do I specify the URL? I see one like this: wss://echo.websocket.org . So is it ws://MY_DOMAIN:MY_PORT? Something like ws://88.88.88.88:9002

Comment: The `ws` (and `wss`) schemes are used from JavaScript running on browser. When you connect from a browser, use `ws://MYHOST:MYPORT/MYPATH` (note the path .. you can have running different WS endpoints on different paths on the same host/port). When you are using standard ports (80/443) with WS, you can leave out the port. When connecting from non-browser clients, simply connect via TCP to MYHOST at MYPORT.

Answer (score 1):

1. No you don't, websocket and socket for an HTTP server are two diffent things.
   HTTP server is for the HTTP protocol while there is not protocol defined for websocket, you have to define it yourself typically by the mean of sending/receiving Json message (a stream of character which each side (the server and the client) knows how to read/write).
   The goal of websocket is to offer to javascript through HTML5 an easy, light and quick way to communicate through a socket, without websocket you have to do that with web services and in that case you need a http server.
   With websocket you can create an html file leveraging html tag and javascript, javascript use client side of websocket to communicate with a C++/websocket server program, and you do not need even a web server, in this scenario you have a "desktop web app" ! (here web term is only because you use html tags)
2. Same question, same answer, no again ;-)

Good luck, and welcome in the wonderful world of asio !